# Solutions of complex equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The equation $$we^{c-w}=1$$ has only one solution in the unit disc for $c>1$. It is easy to show that it has only one real solution in unit disc and that if $w$ is a solution than so is $\overline{w}$. Yet I have no idea how to show that there are no other solutions except that real one.

Comment: The equation seems to hold for such $w$ for which $\Im w = Arg (w)$. This certainly is true for some real $w$.

Comment: @vnd can you expand that?

Comment: Assume $w=x+iy$ and then calculate the imaginary part of the LHS of the original equation. Equating to $0$ the imaginary part, one arrives at the condition $-x \sin y + y \cos y = 0$. Noting that $|w| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, one gets the condition in my prev comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this may not be the most elegant way, but this works:
Since $e^{-c} < 1$, it suffices to show that the equation $we^{-w} = \alpha$, with $|\alpha|<1$, cannot have a complex solution $w$ of modulus $\leq 1$.

Set $w = re^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-w} = r'e^{i\theta'}$, 
with $-\pi<\theta,\ \theta'\leq\pi$ and $r \leq 1$.

Since $\alpha$ is real, we have 
$\theta = -\theta' \pmod{2\pi}$.

But $e^{-w} = e^{-r\cos\theta - ri\sin\theta}$

hence $\theta' = -r\sin\theta$, and $\theta = r\sin\theta \pmod{2\pi}$.

Since $\sin\theta$ and $\theta$ share the same sign on $(-\pi, \pi]$, and since $|\sin\theta|<|\theta|$ for every $\theta \ne 0$ in this interval, we conclude that this last equation is possible only if $\theta=0$, as was to be shown.